# What frame rate is used by iPhone in "30fps" mode?

Tags: iphone, video

I know in the Settings app, it says 30 fps.  But after importing the video files to a computer, QuickTime 7 and X both identify it as 29.98 [sic].  MediaInfo calls it as 29.97.  DaVinci Resolve calls it 30.00.  Which is correct, and is it drop-frame or non-drop?

Comment: 30fps generally means 29.970fps for compatibility with [NTSC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTSC).

Answer (score 2):

30 frames per second is based on NTSC broadcasting standards that go all the way back to the invention of television.  All recording equipment conforms to this spec even though we don't use analog anymore.

NTSC actually runs at 29.975 frames per second, so both your apps are technically correct.  We just say "30fps" because it's easier to say and write than 29.975.

Comment: I wasn't asking for a history lesson. I'm well aware of the 1000/1001 standard. Some devices use true 30.00, and I want to know if the iPhone does this.

Comment: The v-drive is 59.94 fields/sec, or 29.97 frames/sec. Not 29.975